# How to make a link bounce as the page automatically scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My page currently has a header at the top with different links. When the links are clicked, the page automatically scrolls to that part of the page. I'm using this jQuery code for the autoscroll:

```
$("#about").click(function(e){

      var targetOffset= $("#two").offset().top;
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1500);
      e.preventDefault();
```

});

I'd like to use the jQuery UI bounce effect on the link as well, so that it bounces as the page scrolls. How do I make these effects happen at the same time? And also, how do I link to jQuery UI file within the html document?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251109/jquery-animate-with-effect-bounce-after-animation-is-complete

Answer (score 1):

You can set easing like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
```

[see more about easing here](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)